# Get just one data in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like this

```
Array
(
[rows] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
            [0] => 2355
            [1] => 2951
            [2] => kgmf7yUL5Aa
            [3] => P9101083101
            [4] => ANC - JUMLAH ANEMIA DIPERIKSA
            [5] => PUSKESMAS BOMBERAY
            [6] => ANCANEMIAPRKS
            [7] => P9101083101
            [8] => May 2013
            [9] => PUSKESMAS BOMBERAY
            [10] => No
            )
    )
)
```

I just want to get data from `[0] => 2355` 
and insert it to the table like this :

```
<table> 
<tr>
<td>2355</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

how to do it ?

Comment: where did you got stuck? Its multidimensional array

Comment: `$array["rows"][0][0]`

Comment: what is the variable name of your entire array?

Comment: @yotam : i named it $json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $json['rows'][0][0]; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: First to answer (by 3 seconds!). +1

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
foreach($json['rows'] as $k => $value) {
  echo "<table> <tr><td>$value[0]</td></tr></table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it just be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $json['rows'][0][0]; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $json['rows'][0][0] ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```